# Asynchronous nodejs and promises in a loop

Tags: node.js, object, asynchronous, reference

I have some problems understanding asyncronous nodejs in a loop and the associated scope I guess.

Basically, I want to extract different values and store it in a "template" object that I will implement each loop and store in an array of promises in order to use it when resolved.

It might seem (a lot) far fetched  for this code's actual goal but i struggle understanding why does the *promise* variable is only returning the last element each loop even if i pass the index value to the function and use it in *then()*.

Code :

```
(async ()=>{

let tab = ["a","b","c","d"];
let data = { name:"Random Array", data:null, idx:null};
let promise = {};
let promisesArray = [];

for(let i = 0 ; i < tab.length; i++){
 promise = wait(3000).then(()=>{
   let d = data;
   d.data = tab[i];
   d.idx = i;
   d.success = true;
   console.log(d);
   return d;
   });

   promisesArray.push(promise);
}

let fullData = await Promise.all(promisesArray);
console.log(fullData);

})();

function wait(time){
 return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
   setTimeout(resolve,time)
 });
}
```

Output :

```
[{ name: 'Random Array', data: 'd', idx: 3, success: true },
 { name: 'Random Array', data: 'd', idx: 3, success: true },
 { name: 'Random Array', data: 'd', idx: 3, success: true },
 { name: 'Random Array', data: 'd', idx: 3, success: true }]
```

Intended Output :

```
[{ name: 'Random Array', data: 'a', idx: 0, success: true },
 { name: 'Random Array', data: 'b', idx: 1, success: true },
 { name: 'Random Array', data: 'c', idx: 2, success: true },
 { name: 'Random Array', data: 'd', idx: 3, success: true }]
```

Sorry if this is some trivial knowledge but I didn't find anything about it so far.
Thanks in advance for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing is, you're using the same `data` object all the time, so that's why you got 4 exactly same objects in your array, it's all due to this line in your loop:

```
let d = data;
```

You just assigning `data` to `d`, it doesn't make a copy of `data`, but now they both have a reference to the **same** `data` object. If you just copied value of `data` into `d` you would be fine:

```
const d = { ...data }

// or

const d = { name:"Random Array", data:null, idx:null}

// or 

const getData = () => ({ name:"Random Array", data:null, idx:null})
const d = getData()
```

Hope it helps <3

Comment: Thanks! God I feel so stupid that was obvious. Thanks again for your time